# Intellij IDEA throws ClassNotFoundException while Debugging

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I had installed Intellij IDEA only two days back. Before that I was using Eclipse. As a result I imported all my Eclipse projects in IDEA. Everything was going fine, I had run and debug one or two classes and then I decided to replace the Intellij preinstalled JDK with the one installed on my computer. After that whenever I clicked `RUN` on a class it would execute perfectly but when I clicked Debug, it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`

[image]

I have tried disabling the `Breakpoint on Java Exception Option in Run/View Breakpoints` but it is of no use.

Comment: Right click on the class and choose Debug option

Comment: Right click on the class in the project explorer or somewhere else ?

Comment: Project explorer or on the editor panel itself of that class

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a typo in your configuration. Your class is named "BlockedWebsite.java" but your compiler is looking for "BlockedWebsite**s**.java".

Comment: How to fix that ?

Comment: Really? Try Googling it before making someone on the internet spend time to find your answer. If somehow you don't know what to search, "intellij specify main class for project" will show your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried clicking the Invalidate Caches and Restart and it solved the problem...thanks to whoever gave the answer and deleted it the next moment....guess IDEA was not recompiling the class with the new JDK and clearing the cache forced it to do so